# cant access running container root and the image as well

Tags: docker, dockerfile, containers

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b63vv.png)
My docker compose file seems to be running just fine and in the docker dashboard I see the appropriate containers working.

When I go to http://localhost:6001/ all I see is an error message which reads:

> 'This page isn’t working. localhost didn’t send any data. ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE'.

I am not sure how to solve this. I saw somewhere to replace localhost with '0.0.0.0', but am not sure how to do that in this context and I feel like I have seen it work with localhost so I am not sure what to do with the information.

I have checked other sources to see what I am doing incorrectly and am not finding a good solution. I would love to ask for any advice on this matter!

My `Dockerfile`:

```
#See https://aka.ms/containerfastmode to understand how Visual Studio uses this Dockerfile to build your images for faster debugging.

#Depending on the operating system of the host machines(s) that will build or run the containers, the image specified in the FROM statement may need to be changed.
#For more information, please see https://aka.ms/containercompat

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:3.1 AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80
EXPOSE 443

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:3.1 AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["TestDocker.csproj", "."]
RUN dotnet restore "./TestDocker.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/."
RUN dotnet build "TestDocker.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "TestDocker.csproj" -c Release -o /app/publish

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "TestDocker.dll"]
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2oZou.png)

Comment: How are you actually starting the container?  What are the images you've attached to the question?

Comment: I tried both the ways - from docker desktop tool and by docker run -p 6001:8080 command (browsing localhost:6001 port) as well. No luck

Answer (score -1):

Just try accessing using 127.0.0.1 instead of localhost.

Comment: Still the same, not working

I tried using - http://127.0.0.1:6001/weatherforecast - 


and the response is This site can’t be reached127.0.0.1 took too long to respond.
Try:

Checking the connection
Checking the proxy and the firewall
Running Windows Network Diagnostics
ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT

Comment: Hi Raghu, Can you share me the sample docker file for .Net 5.0 for asp.netcore webapi template?